# How to migrate Managed Azure API Developer Portal(not legacy) Content to new instances

Tags: azure, api, azure-api-management, portal

Using scripts https://github.com/Azure/api-management-developer-portal/wiki/Migrate-portal-between-services, I was able to retrieve all definitions and deploy to a new instance, the problem was that only legacy Portal was migrated, new portal was not. How can we migrate the new Developer portal? I couldn't find any settings or reference in the scripts or documentation, I also tried changing the version  of the api scripts currently have it as 2018-06-01-preview, but that also failed.

Answer (score 0):

Running the scripts on a mac did not return any results for calls made to the Azure API(not for the capture.js, neither for the generate.js), had to make some changes to the js files and create .sh scripts.

migrate.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#Migrate the content of an API Management portal from one service instance to another - incl. pages, layouts, configuration, media files, etc.

# BEGIN: provide all the required parameters. If your portal is self-hosted, use the storage account connection string from the config.design.json file. If your portal is managed, refer to the documentation for instructions on accessing its storage account connection string.
export source_management_endpoint="< source_service_name >.management.azure-api.net"
export source_access_token="SharedAccessSignature ..."
export source_storage_connection_string="DefaultEndpointsProtocol= ..."

export target_management_endpoint="< target_service_name >.management.azure-api.net"
export target_access_token="SharedAccessSignature..."
export target_storage_connection_string="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=..."
# END: provide all the required parameters.

export data_file="../dist/data.json"
export media_folder="../dist/content"
export media_container="content"

# Quotes are important in the parameters especially in the case of access_tokens, they have spaces in their values, that will throw off the js scripts.
# Capture the content of the source portal (excl. media)
node ./capture "$source_management_endpoint" "$source_access_token" "$data_file"

# Remove all the content of the target portal (incl. media)
node ./cleanup "$target_management_endpoint" "$target_access_token" "$target_storage_connection_string"

# Upload the content of the source portal (excl. media)
node ./generate "$target_management_endpoint" "$target_access_token" "$data_file"

# Download the media files from the source portal
mkdir "$media_folder"
az storage blob download-batch --source "$media_container" --destination "$media_folder" --connection-string "$source_storage_connection_string"

# Upload the media files to the target portal
az storage blob upload-batch --source "$media_folder" --destination "$media_container" --connection-string "$target_storage_connection_string"

#At this point your target API Management service should contain the same content of the portal as the source service. To make the portal of the target service available to visitors, you still need to publish it and, in case of a self-hosted version, host the generated files.
```

Had to change the request function for capture.js and generate.js, original code is using string to capture payload, changing  it to a Buffer Array, solved in my case. Here is the new request

capture.js

```
async function request(url){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
         const req = https.get(url,options, (res) =>{
            let bodyChunks = [];
            res.on('data', (chunk)=> {
                bodyChunks.push(chunk);
            }).on('end', ()=> {
                let body = Buffer.concat(bodyChunks);
                // console.log('BODY: ' + body);
                try {
                    resolve(JSON.parse(body));
                }
                catch (e) {
                    reject(e);

                }
            })
        })
        req.on('error', (e)=> {
            console.log('ERROR: ' + e.message);
            reject(e);
        })
        req.end();
    })
}
```

generate.js

```
async function request(url,body){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        const options = {
            port: 443,
            method: "PUT",
            headers: {
                "If-Match": "*",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Content-Length": Buffer.byteLength(body),
                "Authorization": accessToken
            }
        };
        const req = https.request(url,options, (res) =>{
            let bodyChunks = [];
            res.on('data', (chunk)=> {
                bodyChunks.push(chunk);
            }).on('end', ()=> {
                let data = Buffer.concat(bodyChunks);
                // console.log('DATA: ' + data);
                try {
                    resolve(JSON.parse(data));
                }
                catch (e) {
                    console.log(url);
                    reject(e);

                }
            })
        })
        req.on('error', (e)=> {
            console.log('ERROR: ' + e.message);
            reject(e);
        });
        req.write(body);
        req.end();
    })
}
```